# how to insert other column as session

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this in my session

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

how can I calling other column which is `user_id` as session and insert into new table as current user that do insert action.

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you mean? You want to create new `$_SESSION` variable? Also, why are you checking if the `$_SESSION` variable is set, and then check to if it's empty? That's redundant.

Comment: @Samuel  yupp.. create new variable, is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create `$_SESSION` variables, it is fairly easy and straight forward. They are each element arrays.

You mentioned in your question that you wanted the `user_id` session variable, so just create the session array with the key of `user_id`.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = USER_ID;
$_SESSION['username'] = USER_NAME;
$_SESSION['email'] = USER_EMAIL;
//...
```

For more information on how to work with `$_SESSION` variables read [PHP's Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: Do i need to pass from login page or just declaire in the session? sorry for asking..

Comment: You can set it at any time. If you are using mysql, you should pull it with the `username`, and whatever variable you are asking for. That will depend greatly on your login structure, but either way, you can set `$_SESSION` to whatever value you may want. You need to declare it, though. Your script will not assume a `$_SESSION` value for you.